# Reverting Anaconda compiler back to GCC 7.3.0

Tags: python, gcc, anaconda, clang

This question is about reverting a mistake I made. I was trying to solve some issue with installing a perl package from source, but I ended up changing my default Anaconda python C compiler to clang 10.0.0.

Now, the header line reads

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 11:26:31) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
```

when I run python, instead of

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on
```

The piece of code I ran was:

```
conda install clangxx_osx-64
export CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)
```

I would like to revert this and take it back to GCC. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I know this has changed my conda_build_config.yaml too, and so below I am posting some of the relevant lines that I think have been changed:

```
.
.
c_compiler: clang
c_compiler_version: '10'
.
.
cxx_compiler: clangxx
cxx_compiler_version: '10'
.
.
macos_machine: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
```

Comment: Have you looked at `conda list --revisions`?

Comment: [tag:compiler-construction] is for questions about *writing* compilers, not using them.